# passing html as a string into webView

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to pass in a a html string as and just getting a blank screen i have tried both loadData and loadDataWithBaseUrl and getting nothing does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Heres what i have tried so far

```
        final WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(
                Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                    String url) {

                webview.loadData(url, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


        });


        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, editedHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     WebView webview = new WebView(this);
     setContentView(webview);

     String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
     webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

}
```

this will create a webview and show "You scored 192 points" in the html.  make sure you have internet permission on your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same:

```
 public class WebActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 String customHtml = "<html><body><h2>Hello World</h2></body></html>";
 webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}

}
```